Calculate the difference between two dates and calculate the sum and the average for them
I work in sql server and I have two rows in my table  :

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in hours, minutes, and seconds and then calculate the average and the sum for the results, I tried this to calculate the difference:
    SELECT CONCAT(format(DATEDIFF(SECOND, started_at, ended_at)/3600,'00'),':'
              ,format(DATEDIFF(SECOND, started_at, ended_at)%3600/60,'00'),':'
              ,format(DATEDIFF(SECOND, started_at, ended_at)%3600%60,'00')
             ) AS 'hrs:mins:secnds'

but the problem is the new column  'hrs:mins:secnds' is a string and  I could not perform mathematical operations on it. Is there a way to calculate the difference between the two dates and calculate the average and the sum?

Please dont post images of text information,.  How is anyone supposed to copy the data to try it out?

Help me write this query in SQL

Is the difference ever more than 24hrs?

Follow the SQL Script. There are comments at each step.  This script has been tested in SQL Server Version 2008 and 2014.
--#1 Create the table
CREATE TABLE #TimeTable(started_at datetime, ended_at datetime);
--#2 Inserting Data
INSERT INTO #TimeTable
VALUES
 ('2023-08-10 10:36:00', '2023-08-10 10:49:30')
,('2023-10-11 17:23:00', '2023-10-11 17:36:00')
,('2023-10-12 07:02:00', '2023-10-12 07:06:00')
,('2023-10-24 19:13:00', '2023-10-24 19:18:00');

--#3 Calculate difference between two times in Seconds Column(DD). 
-- Then in days, hours, minutes and seconds.
SELECT Started_At, Ended_At, DATEDIFF("s",Started_At,Ended_At) as DD,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEDIFF(SECOND,Started_At,Ended_At) / 60 / 60 / 24) AS ' Day(s) '
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEDIFF(SECOND,Started_At,Ended_At) / 60 / 60 % 24) AS ' Hour(s) '
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEDIFF(SECOND,Started_At,Ended_At) / 60 % 60) AS ' Minute(s) '
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEDIFF(SECOND,Started_At,Ended_At) % 60) AS ' Second(s) '
FROM #TimeTable ;

-- #4 Calculate the average and the sum
WITH Step1
AS 
(
SELECT Started_At, Ended_At, DATEDIFF(SECOND,Started_At,Ended_At) as DD
FROM #TimeTable
)
-- *** Calculate the average and the sum 
SELECT AVG(DD) AS AVG_Sec, SUM(DD) AS Sum_Sec, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), AVG(DD) / 60 / 60 / 24) AS ' Day(s) ' --AVG
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), AVG(DD)/ 60 / 60 % 24) AS ' Hour(s) ' --AVG
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), AVG(DD) / 60 % 60) AS ' Minute(s) ' --AVG
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), AVG(DD) % 60) AS ' Second(s) ' --AVC

,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SUM(DD) / 60 / 60 / 24) AS ' SDay(s) ' --SUM
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SUM(DD)/ 60 / 60 % 24) AS ' SHour(s) ' --SUM
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUM(DD) / 60 % 60) AS ' SMinute(s) ' --SUM
,+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUM(DD) % 60) AS ' SSecond(s) ' --SUM
FROM STEP1;

drop table #TimeTable;


I think what he required is calculate each row's different, and sum all diffs together, then calc average of all diffs.
If my understanding is correct, we can use window function to attach sum and avg as 2 columns.
To make the code clear, I use CTE do the calculation, and normal query to format the output.
CREATE TABLE #TEST(started_at datetime, ended_at datetime)
GO
INSERT INTO #TEST
VALUES
 ('2023-08-10 10:36:00', '2023-08-10 11:49:31')
,('2023-10-11 17:46:00', '2023-10-11 19:33:00')
,('2023-10-12 07:02:00', '2023-10-12 07:06:00')
GO

WITH R
AS
(
    SELECT 
         started_at
        ,ended_at
        ,DATEDIFF(SECOND, started_at, ended_at) AS diff
        ,SUM(DATEDIFF(Second, started_at, ended_at)) OVER() AS S
        ,AVG(DATEDIFF(Second, started_at, ended_at)) OVER() AS V
    FROM
        #TEST
)
SELECT 
    started_at
    ,ended_at
    ,CONCAT(format(diff/3600,'00'),':',format(diff%3600/60,'00'),':',format(diff%3600%60,'00')) AS [different(hrs:mins:secnds)]
    ,CONCAT(format(S/3600,'00'),':',format(S%3600/60,'00'),':',format(S%3600%60,'00')) AS [Sum(hrs:mins:secnds)]
    ,CONCAT(format(V/3600,'00'),':',format(V%3600/60,'00'),':',format(V%3600%60,'00')) AS [Average(hrs:mins:secnds)]
FROM
    R

GO
DROP TABLE #TEST
GO


An explanation of what this answer is doing would really help here.

@ThomA Roger that! I had update the answer. Thank you!
